# How to change language of header of Alert box in java

Tags: javafx, header, alert

I am translating my tool in Arabic language.
For this, All alert box , message box have to be in Arabic language.
The message to be printed is no issue, But the main issue is ,
How to change language of header of Alert box in Java.

Alert in below code spinet is from package "javafx.scene.control"

```
Alert confirmationDialog = dialog.createAndReturn("restartAppointment",DialogButtons.YES);
final Optional<ButtonType> result = confirmationDialog.showAndWait();
```

Above code gives me an alert box like this.
[Message box having header as "WARNING"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj81J.png)

Please tell me , how to change its language into Arabic?

Comment: use `confirmationDialog.setTitle("تنبيه")`

Comment: Thanks Biju. It worked.